# I am getting a undefined error for my dataFactory in angularJs

Tags: angularjs

I am writing a simple MVC pattern in pure HTML and AngularJS and I have succeeded making a controller. I have been following the guidelines in:

http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/using-an-angularjs-factory-to-interact-with-a-restful-service

Now my next goal was to make a factory that is providing data.

I have organized my files as following:
- shell page called 'index.html'
- core libraries with 'angular.min.js' and 'angular-route.min.js'
- views, controllers and factories

Routing is working fine and also giving me the views by showing their HTML. So far hard-coded data was providing me with data to bind with my `<div ng-view></div>`.

Here is a part of my HTML. I thought that it might have something to do with the order of my references of my *.js files:

```
<body>
    <!-- Placeholder -->
    <div ng-view></div>

    <!-- Core libs -->
    <script type="application/javascript" src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript"  src="scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Routing -->
    <script type="application/javascript" src="app/app.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom scripts -->
    <script type="application/javascript" src="app/factories/characterFactory.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="app/controllers/characterController.js"></script>

</body>
```

In my 'app.js' file I have my routing logic, which is working fine...

Here is my view page, which is also working fine when using hard-coded data from my controller:

```
<b>Here is the characterlist page</b>

    <div data-ng-controller="characterController">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr data-ng-repeat="character in characters| orderBy:['status','points']:true">
                    <td><a href="character.html?id={{ character.id }}">{{ character.name }}</a></td><td>{{ character.city }} | {{ character.age }} years | {{ character.points }} | {{ character.status }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Now I have hard-coded my data in my 'dataFactory'.
Here is the code for my 'dataFactory':

```
var app;
app.factory('dataFactory', ['$http', function ($http) {
    'use strict';
    var dataFactory = {};
    //alert('it works until here')
    dataFactory.getCharacters = function () {
        var characters = [
            {id: '1', name: 'Luke', points: '30', city: 'Berlin', status: 'online', age: '38'},
            {id: '2', name: 'Peter', points: '40', city: 'Stockhom', status: 'online', age: '28'},
            {id: '3', name: 'Scully', points: '50', city: 'Paris', status: 'offline', age: '18'},
            {id: '4', name: 'Vader', points: '20', city: 'London', status: 'online', age: '26'},
            {id: '5', name: 'Skywalker', points: '10', city: 'Malmö', status: 'offline', age: '14'}
        ];
        return characters;
    };
}]);
```

I have been trying to figure out why I keep getting an undefined error on my 'dataFactory' object.

This is my controller code:

```
var app;
app.controller('characterController', ['$scope', '$http', 'dataFactory', function ($scope, $http, dataFactory) {
    'use strict';
    dataFactory.getCharacters().then(function (res) {
        $scope.characters = res.data.result;
    });
}]);
```

I get this error when I am using Firebug's javascript console:

Error: dataFactory is undefined

Can anyone shed some light on what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several problems most important of which is :

Your factory doesn't return anything!

You return `characters` within a function in the factory but you don't return the object `datafactory` from the actual factory.

```
app.factory('dataFactory', ['$http', function ($http) {
    'use strict';
    var dataFactory = {};
    /* add properties, methods etc to the object  */

     /* return the object from factory*/
     return datafactory;
})
```

Once you resolve that you are treating the return as a promise but there is no promise created in your factory.

Therefore you can simply do

```
$scope.characters =  dataFactory.getCharacters();
```

This however wouldn't work if your `getCharacters()` method was asynchronous and you would then return something like $htp , $resource etc which involve promises

Comment: Awww...darn that was obvious...inserting a return statement now.

Comment: After correcting the return statement and the simple way of returning the data (which I actually started with), I am now getting this error:
https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/areq?p0=characterController&p1=not%20a%20function,%20got%20undefined

Comment: use the full version of angular for more verbose error output ( not min version)

Comment: but click that link and it tells you something wrrong with a controller, for example it might be in your html but not defined on `app`

Comment: might be due to the extra `var app`'s you have. It's all one variable starting at module

Comment: I am using Brackets and even though my code is separated in multiple .js files, brackets validates my javascript as correct, if I have declared app (var app;) before using it...

Comment: doesn't matter, combined together you wipe out prior declarations

Comment: A typo in my controller name. Works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your factory, you can return a promise, which you can resolve with `.then(response)` in your controller

```
app.factory('dataFactory', ['$http', function ($http) {

    function getCharacters() {
        return $http.get(//.. ajax details)
    }

    return {
        'getCharacters': getCharacters
    }
}]);
```

Comment: how could OP get undefined on factory if angular wasn't being bootstrapped?

Comment: unsure, but I see `var app;` on top of both files

Answer (score 0):

You have just missed a return statement:

```
var app;
app.factory('dataFactory', ['$http', function ($http) {
    'use strict';
    var dataFactory = {};
    //alert('it works until here')
    dataFactory.getCharacters = function () {
        var characters = [
            {id: '1', name: 'Luke', points: '30', city: 'Berlin', status: 'online', age: '38'},
            {id: '2', name: 'Peter', points: '40', city: 'Stockhom', status: 'online', age: '28'},
            {id: '3', name: 'Scully', points: '50', city: 'Paris', status: 'offline', age: '18'},
            {id: '4', name: 'Vader', points: '20', city: 'London', status: 'online', age: '26'},
            {id: '5', name: 'Skywalker', points: '10', city: 'Malmö', status: 'offline', age: '14'}
        ];
        return characters;
    };

    return dataFactory; // <- here

}]);
```

Note that you are not using promises so you are not allowed to do:

```
dataFactory.getCharacters().then(...)
```

The correct way of getting variable is:

```
var chs = dataFactory.getCharacters(); // then use it
```

Unless you implement your factory using [angular $q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).